# rows object returned after executing stored procedure in node-mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, stored-procedures

I've a subquery executing and was looking for insertId's but I'm getting a rows object with no information.

**My stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `day`(IN start DATE, IN end DATE, IN event_id INT)
BEGIN
    WHILE start <= end DO
        INSERT INTO day(date, event_id) VALUES(start, event_id);
        SET start = start + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

**Node.js**

```
var query = "SET @start = '" + request.body.from  + "'; \
    SET @end = '" + request.body.to + "'; \
    SET @event_id = " + rows.insertId + "; \
    CALL day(@start, @end, @event_id);";

connection.query(query, [], function(error, rows, fields) {
    console.log(rows);
}
```

**Console output for the `rows`**

```
[
    {
      "fieldCount": 0,
      "affectedRows": 0,
      "insertId": 0,
      "serverStatus": 11,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "message": "",
      "protocol41": true,
      "changedRows": 0
    },
    {
      "fieldCount": 0,
      "affectedRows": 0,
      "insertId": 0,
      "serverStatus": 11,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "message": "",
      "protocol41": true,
      "changedRows": 0
    },
    {
      "fieldCount": 0,
      "affectedRows": 0,
      "insertId": 0,
      "serverStatus": 11,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "message": "",
      "protocol41": true,
      "changedRows": 0
    },
    {
      "fieldCount": 0,
      "affectedRows": 1,
      "insertId": 0,
      "serverStatus": 3,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "message": "",
      "protocol41": true,
      "changedRows": 0
    }
  ]
```

**Expectations and Question**

I need some kind of actual information as a result of the insertions by stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Does that stored procedure actually return anything? My stored procedure would define a variable to hook into with a `returning` would look like this:

```
DECLARE
  the_id integer;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO the_table (first, last, address, zip)
  VALUES (first, last, address, zip)
  RETURNING _id INTO the_id;

RETURN the_id;

END;
```

The `RETURN` actually sends the ID to the output.

*Disclaimer: I work with PostgreSQL and write functions in plpsql, but I believe the syntax is similar.*

Comment: thanks Joel, but will it return multiple values, my stored procedure is a loop, inserting number of records based on start and end date

Comment: No - that would only return one value. I believe you can wrap your query in a ``return()`` or simply put ``AS`` before the ``BEGIN``. You might also want to look into ``REF CURSOR`` types but I am not well versed in that syntax.